# How to quickly set large numbers of consecutively coloured texture pixels in C#

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, optimization, textures

I'm trying to draw a large wide custom texture (approx 2000x200 pixels) in Unity (C#) where all the consecutive vertical pixels in each column are in two blocks.  A first block of the same colour, then a second block of transparent pixels.   Each column has different numbers of coloured pixels, and different colours from each other.

Effectively, this is a vertical bar chart, with a couple of thousand 1 pixel wide bars.

This texture needs to be updated around once per second.

My initial implementation is quite slow and causes frame-rate spikes when setting the pixel colours.  I'm therefore looking for ideas on the fastest way to accomplish this.

My current code is roughly as follows:

Start of Day:

```
Color32[] m_pixelData = new Color32[width * height];
Texture2D m_texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
Color32 m_transparent = new Color32(0,0,0,0);
```

Each Update:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    Color32 barColor = CalculateBarColorForThisColumn(x);
    int barHeight = CalculateBarHeightForThisColumn(x);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        int pixelIndex = y * width + x;

        if (y <= barHeight)
            m_pixelData[pixelIndex] = barColor;
        else
            m_pixelData[pixelIndex] = m_transparent;
    }
}
m_texture.SetPixels32(m_pixelData);
```

Is there a faster way to do this, or is this as good as it gets and to improve performance of the overall program, would need to push this work onto a background thread?

Comment: You wrote "once per second" but in the code section you say "each update". So first of all, you might want to decide for one or the other. Then it seems (I'm guessing though) that you add new "bars" only at one end? If so copy the rest of the texture first https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.CopyTexture.html and only set individual pixels on the last bar. I guess your question could have a tad more context.

Comment: And to add: Do not set pixels on textures that are shown on screen. Set the pixels in an in-memory texture first and then flip the used texture with the new one.

Comment: Thank you - to clarify that second snippet of code should say "Each time I update the texture" (i.e. once per second), and *not* imply "each call to Update()".

Answer (score 0):

As for the implementation, this seems pretty standard, but yes there are a lot of ways to optimize this, but know that none are trivial and all have drawbacks.

#### Batching

Since you are updating the texture only once per seconds, you could divide the workload through multiple frames and set the pixels only once every seconds.

#### Parallel

You could convert your for loop to be multi-threaded. In Unity, multi-threading is always tricky, but in this case, it should be pretty straightforward using `Parallel.ForEach`

#### Compute Shader

By far the fastest solution. Non-trivial, certainly, but has the best performance in your case. The drawback is that it only works with compute-enabled GPU, so not WebGL and some old devices.

#### Custom Shader

On a different approach, you could use a custom shader instead of setting a texture manually. In term of doing what you want (the end result), this is the fastest solution with the least drawbacks.

If you have any questions on a specific implementation, I can provide some insight and / or sample code.

Comment: Thank you - I'm currently using batching; doing a few hundred columns at a time, spread out over several frames, but as you say, there are definitely drawbacks with that as the data is changing underfoot, so you get some slight screen-tearing like effects.

Custom shader definitely sounds interesting - any further thoughts you had here would be really appreciated.